# Why won't my Div center itself in its parent?

Tags: css, html, center

I am making a header bar for a website. This header bar consists of 3 parts: The Back Button, The School Information, and The Login Button. The problem is that the center div, the School Information, will not center itself. I've tried everything I know how to do and nothing works.

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
/* -- Button Bar -- */

.buttonbarframe {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #D5D5D5;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 /*height: 65px;*/
 height: 45px;
 
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

/*#buttonbar {
    width: 100%;
 height: 45px;
 padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}*/

.buttonbarspan {
    height: 100%;
}

.buttonbarspanindex {
    width: inherit;
    height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
}

#buttonbarschoolimage {
    display: block;
    float: left;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}

#buttonbarschoolname {
    display: block;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-top: 4px;
 text-align: left;
 vertical-align: middle;
 float: left;
}

.buttonbarrightbutton {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

.buttonbarsycamorelogo {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 44px;
}

.schoolstuff {
    display: inline-block;  
    margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 341px;
}

.rightbutton {
    float: right;
}

.leftbutton {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='buttonbarframe'>
    <div class='leftbutton buttonbarspan'>
        <a class='backbutton btn btn-large btn-danger' href=''><i class='icon-white icon-arrow-left'></i> Logout</a>
    </div>
    <div class='schoolstuff buttonbarspan'>
        <img id='buttonbarschoolimage' src='/Schools/$EntityValue/logo'>
        <h2 id='buttonbarschoolname'>Tri-County School</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='rightbutton buttonbarspan'>
        <input type='submit' class='buttonbarrightbutton btn btn-large btn-primary' href='parentcheckin.php' value='Login'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of the problem.

[Image of the problem. http://www.overclock.net/image/id/6330507/width/900/height/900/flags/LL](http://www.overclock.net/image/id/6330507/width/900/height/900/flags/LL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting `text-align: center` on the parent div will fix this issue. What you have right now centers the text in the div which should already be centered.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/AJmSw/

Inline-block elements will be positioned based on the parent containers text align. With both your side divs floating this will work fine.

Alternatively removing the `display: inline-block` rule from the center div will allow the `margin: 0 auto;` to take effect also centering the div
see: http://jsfiddle.net/b4mWU/

Comment: since when is there text align middle ??

Comment: This isn't doing anything for me. I did exactly what I saw on jsfiddle and nothing happened.

Comment: Inspect the div, you most likely have another style overriding it

Comment: Yeah I tried both of these. It's frustrating when something works in jsfiddle but not in anywhere else. I'm using twitter Bootstrap. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: I inspected the div and all children. It doesn't seem that anything is overriding it.

Comment: If there is no other css then no the bootstrap shouldnt matter. Try isolating the issue, add more from  your page to the fiddle until you can recreate the issue, at which point you can identify and fix it

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap was being stupid. There was a CSS problem that flew under the radar for me. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: could you post your solution?